# std::atomic_flag and std::lock_guard

Tags: c++11, locking, atomic

Since `std::lock_guard` doesn't work with `std::atomic_flag` I've implemented my own version:

```
class atomic_guard {
public:
    inline atomic_guard(std::atomic_flag& lock) : lock(lock) {
        while (this->lock.test_and_set()) {
            /* spin */ 
        };
    };

    inline ~atomic_guard() {
        this->lock.clear();
    };

private:
    std::atomic_flag& lock;
};
```

This seems to work fine. The question is: is this a correct way to implement RAII for `std::atomic_flag`? Also is there a built-in guard for that? If not, why? The specialization `std::lock_guard<std::atomic_flag>` looks like something very natural.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your use of `atomic_guard` as a standalone mutex lookalike is correct, if slightly unusual.

Using `std::atomic_flag` directly with `std::lock_guard` is not possible because the `std::lock_guard` template manages a mutex while `std::atomic_flag` is a (low-level) atomic boolean type.

A mutex implementation that can be used with `std::lock_guard` has to provide member functions `lock` and `unlock` and can be implemented like this:

```
class my_mutex {
    std::atomic_flag flag{ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT};

public:
    void lock()
    {
        while (flag.test_and_set());
    }

    void unlock()
    {
        flag.clear();
    }
};
```

Note that this is a very basic and inefficient mutex implementation, but it is compatible with `std::lock_guard`:

```
my_mutex mtx;

std::lock_guard<my_mutex> lck{mtx};
```

Comment: What do you mean by `inefficient`? Isn't atomic_flag more efficient then standard mutex? At least for some cases, e.g. when the locking time is supposed to be short.

Comment: @freakish If a thread is waiting to acquire the lock using `my_mutex`, it is wasting a lot of CPU time since it is in a busy `while` loop

Comment: I wouldn't call that "wasting". You gain execution time, so its a tradeof. It seems that atomic_flag can be even ~50x faster then standard mutex. So if you lock for a short period then "wasting" these cpu cycles might be worth it. Here's the benchmark: https://www.arangodb.com/2015/02/comparing-atomic-mutex-rwlocks/ Of course I will do proper tests in my scenario, but I do expect at least 2x speedup.

Comment: But I do like your `my_mutex` implementation. I didn't know that you can use `std::lock_guard` with a custom class (and that it is so easy). That's very nice.

Comment: @freakish I have done some performance comparison with a `std::mutex` (easy to replace in `lock_guard`).. Usually the standard library mutex wins. Obviously that implementation is more advanced. I believe it also loops for a short time before a context switch is performed